# How to store large object in html data attribute without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I have an angular project I'm working on where I'm trying to store an object that's being populated from a server in an HTML data attribute. This object looks something like this:

```
{"decimalPlaces": "2", "soft": "false"}
```

I've seen other solutions on stack overflow but they use jquery and I can't use that here. What I would like to be able to do is just feed the entire object to one HTML data attribute rather than have one data attribute for every property in this object. I would like for it to look something like the below line, and then be able to pull out precise data as needed from the angular component.ts file:

```
data-everything="allData"
```

And NOT like this

```
data-decimals="allData.decimalPlaces"
data-soft="allData.soft"
```

Is this possible? Also I have tried JSON.stringify as suggested in other solutions as well, in addition to console.dir to see if I could pull any data out of this "allData" but neither helped.

Comment: Why not just store it as a new JavaScript object property on the HTML element's DOM object? ...or store it in a `Map` (keyed by `element.id`) object inside your application code? If you're using Angular you should not manipulate the DOM directly anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying I should do something like this in html? [attr.data-allData]="allData"